# Update() not working in MongoDB

Tags: c#, mongodb

MongoDB for C#, I started following their tutorial but the compile error I get is on this line:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/CSharp+Driver+Quickstart

```
 var update = Update.Set("Name", "Harry");
```

saying

> System.Windows.Forms.Control.Update()' is a 'method', which is not
>   valid in the given context.

The only difference I see is that they have used a Console Application but I created a C#WinForms applications and pasted their code inside a button click .

Comment: What is the rest of the code? where did you take it from.  Sounds like you should qualify Update, but it's hard to tell with what you have here.

Comment: @pms1969 : Oh sorry, forgot to paste the link to the code..post updated.

Comment: the bottom of that tutorial has a link to a forum hosted by the guys who made the tutorial for the specific purpose of being able to ask them questions about it :P though youll get a wider range of answers here, probably faster too i guess

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update is simply ambiguous in the context you are using the call.  You need to qualify the Update statement to include the namespace it is in.

```
var update = MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Update.Set("Name", "Harry");
```

This will probably get annoying, so you can also create an alias in your header.

```
using U = MongoDB.Driver.Builders.Update;
```

Then, you can change your statement to be this:

```
var update = U.Set("Name", "Harry");
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess your c#WinForms contains an method called Update, which c# tries to access instead of the MongoDB one. Have you checked that you're imported everything needed and that your accessing the right Object?

Comment: Stuck to Craigs answer detailed information on howto resolve it. (I'm just a java boy)